# How to add middleware in Rails 4.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rack-middleware

I am trying to learn `Middlewares` and been practising how to mount it in the Rails application. I have followed the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?autoplay=true)

So far I have implemented these steps:

1) Created a new `Rails 4.2` application called: Blog

2) Added a file in the `lib` folder named as `response_timer.rb`.

```
class ResponseTimer
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, "Hello World"]
  end
end
```

3) Added `config.middleware.use "ResponseTimer"` in `application.rb`.

```
config.middleware.use "ResponseTimer"
```

But as i'm hitting the command `rake middleware` in the terminal, it is reporting this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ResponseTimer
```

I tried also to add the `config.middleware.use "ResponseTimer"` in the `development.rb` but again facing the same error.

What am i missing here?

Please help.

Referenced article: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: try adding your code along with the question, that will be helpful for others to understand this better.

Comment: have you tried requiring the file in `application.rb`, ex: `require_relative '../lib/response_timer'`

Comment: Updated the question. Also this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/24122424

Comment: Yes as per my answer it is working.

Comment: really your answer ??. :) all the best.

Comment: Exactly not my answer. As I told I followed this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24122424) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleware has to have an accompanying module / class, and needs to be loaded in the app before it can be referenced. The way to do this in Rails is with [`autoloading`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4) (`lib` files aren't autoloaded by default):

```
#config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.middleware.use "ResponseTimer"
```

The above should work for you.

Comment: `autoload_paths` is not working :( If I do `rails server` then `uninitialized constant Blog::Application::ResponseTimer (NameError)` And If I do `rake middleware` then `NameError: uninitialized constant Blog::Application::ResponseTimer
`

Comment: Note, in Rails 5+ you can no longer use the String for the name of the middleware. You need to use the proper class name. Additionally, according to @rafaelfranca (Rails core), _"middleware can't be in app because they can't be reloaded. They should be in lib and if you put them in lib, require_relative will work."_ https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25525#issuecomment-479941866

Answer (score -2):

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122424

I tried it before but maybe  missed something before.

In `appliation.rb`

```
require 'rails/all'
require_relative '../lib/response_timer'
module Blog
 class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.middleware.use ResponseTimer
 end
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to include the file explicitly, it's an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: @RichPeck I am sure what you have pointed out is absolutely correct but `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` isn't this line doing the same stuff except its calling the entire `lib` folder where as in the given answer its just calling one file. can you please explain a bit.

Comment: It's autoloading the lib folder, so you don't need to explicitly call the files you need in your `application.rb`.